# Painting app using FBO in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, fbo, cinder

I am working on an application in C++ and OpenGL (using Cinder library).

It is simply getting mouse input, and in the draw method draws circles on the mouse position to the FBO. After that the FBO is drawn to the screen. The FBO isn't cleared everytime, so the previous circles are still in it. The problem is that when I draw new circle to the FBO, it isn't drawn on top of it, but instead under the previous content of the FBO. The FBO is created only with width and height parameters and no other settings. It's also cleared in the setup().

Comment: What if you disable depth testing? glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

Comment: How about marking this question as answered?